# Questions about the plurigenera of a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

These questions seem rather elementary but I am trying to understand them better.

Let $K$ be the canonical divisor of a surface $S$. The symbol $\equiv$ stands for algebraic equivalence of divisors.

1. Why is it the case that if we have $mK \equiv 0$ for some positive integer $m$, then it seems to follow that the $m$-th plurigenus $P_m(S)$ is nonzero? In particular, when do we have $P_m(S) = 1$?

We have $P_1(S) = h^0(S, \mathcal{O}_S(K))$ and by Serre duality, this is the geometric genus $p_g(S)$.

2. The *irregularity* $q$ of $S$ is the difference $p_g(S) - p_a(S) = h^1(\mathcal{O}_S)$, and we know that the arithmetic genus is non-negative. How is it possible that we can have surfaces with $p_g = 0$ but $q \geq 1$?
3. Are there any techniques to compute $h^1(\mathcal{O}_S(K))$? I think by Serre duality it should be $h^0(\mathcal{O}_S)$ and so it has to be $1$? I'm not sure...

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned from what source you are getting these claims. Also in your 3rd point, you are misapplying Serre Duality; specifically, it looks like you are trying to use the statement for curves. In general Serre Duality on an $n$-dimensional variety $X$ relates $H^k(X, L)$ and $H^{n-k}(X, K\otimes L^\vee)$. So on a surface, it allows one to compute $H^2$ groups as $H^0$s, but for the middle cohomology you get $h^1(\mathcal O_S(K)) = h^1(\mathcal O_S) = q(S)$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks for the clarification about question 3, I didn't know about the generalization to $n$-dimensional varieties. For question 2, I think I got it wrong, the general equation is $\chi(\mathcal{O}_S) = 1 - q(S) + p_g(S)$ rather than the one I mentioned because we are talking about a surface, so that's another doubt cleared. As for question 1,  what I want to know is how do we relate the plurigenus $P_n$ being nonzero to the $n$-th multiple of the canonical divisor $nK$ being algebraically equivalent to $0$ as in Beauville, Prop. VI.15. I initially wrote linear equivalence.

Comment: Does your surface have nontrivial line bundles of degree $0$? The basic idea is that if $nK \equiv 0$ then hopefully $\mathcal O_S(nK) \cong \mathcal O_S$, which would then make $P_n(S) = 1$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I've spent some time thinking about it, the second part of your comment did help me understand what $P_n(S) = 1$ is all about. But I am not sure how to check if a surface has nontrivial line bundles of degree $0$ or how is it relevant though...

Comment: A nontrivial line bundle of degree $0$ has no sections, so it's vaguely possible that $nK$ could be numerically trivial but not actually trivial, in which case $P_n(S)=0$.